# Shadowing and garbage collecting in F#

Tags: f#, garbage-collection, shadowing

This is my first time encountering shadowing and there don't seem to be resources specific to my question.

If I do the following

```
let x = a list
let x = another list
```

Then x will hold the contents of the second list.

I assume (based on what my instructor said) that the first list is not automatically destroyed and simply garbage collected at the end of the scope.

My question is why? 
Why do we not automatically get rid of the first list once the immutable is shadowed? It would lead me to think that the data can still somehow be accessed. If so, how?

Comment: Can you identify the course via  online links?. If so, then some of us will give better answers better tailored to the concept the instructor is trying to teach.

Comment: Guy Coder, it's just a class on functional programming paradigms. The discussion started by the code above, and I asked why did this happen and the instructor explained shadowing and that shadowing most likely has no special garbage collection defined, so I assumed it was end of scope. The code above was accidentally copy pasted by the instructor when he meant to declare a new variable, but of course it still worked.

Comment: What do you mean by `end of scope`. I have an idea, but my idea may not be what you are thinking.

Comment: So the above code is declared in main, so end of main aka end of the program the data would be deleted.

Comment: The reason it should not be garbage collected is because if you ever do recursive problem solving, as you unwind the stack back to the point the value on the stack is back in scope then you can branch off of that state into a deeper search.

Comment: OK That works. . . . .

Comment: Ah, that actually makes a ton of sense. Didn't consider the recursive case. Awesome, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming x was the only reference to "a list", then yes, in your code example, "a list" becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Being eligible for garbage collection doesn't however mean that the object is reclaimed at any particular point in the code, particularly not "at the end of the scope". The idea that things get cleaned up at the end of scopes is related to destructors in C++*, GC doesn't work like that at all in .NET. The GC runs concurrently and may or may not reclaim anything eligible at any point in time. That may happen even before the code exits the current scope, or later, or [never](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203). The GC doesn't even care if you have a variable in scope that refers to an object, if you're not using it, it doesn't count (see *liveness analysis*).

*There's a similar mechanism in F#, though: see [use bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
let x = list1
let y = x
let x = list2
```

Now even though you are shadowing `x`, you can still access `list1`. This is just one example -- in general, it's not possible to statically identify all references (*aliases*) to a particular value.  Instead the garbage collector identifies them at runtime.

Obviously in this specific case you might suggest that having some special support would make sense, and indeed perhaps there is -- I don't know myself.